# Comparing strings in java that are already in the memory pool

Tags: java

So I've read that if you write this:

```
String a="foo"; 
String b="foo"; 
System.out.println(a==b);
```

it will print "true", because the first implementation checks the memory pool looking for "foo", it cant find it so it creates a new object and puts foo in the memory pool, then every other string will be pointing to the same object.

and if you write:

```
String a="foo"; 
String b=new String("foo"); 
System.out.println(a==b);
```

it will print "false", because you force a creation of a new object for b so it wont take it from the pool.

my question is if you write this:

```
String a=new String("foo"); 
String b="foo"; 
System.out.println(a==b);
```

why does it still print "false" ? I mean "a" creates a new object and doesn't look in the memory pool, but b should look in the memory pool and find the object "a" created and point to it. what am I missing here? 
thank you.

Comment: a is not in memoryPool, therefore a and b are pointing to dif references....

Comment: `String a=new String("foo");` creates 2 objects. First it creates `"foo"`, then it creates another one with `new String`.

Comment: It's easy, We have a String pool for String purpose, and Object pool for object, you can't compare a String in String pool to a String Object in Object pool using == directly

Comment: `String b=new String("foo");` That's a bad practice, you shouldnt use this. Use `equals` method for comparing strings. `==` tests tests for reference equality while `equals()` tests for value equality.

Comment: @ZsoltÉbel It's bad practice, but people should learn how it works anyway.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of "how do I compare strings in Java", voting to re-open.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new Object it isn't in the pool.

> b should look in the memory pool and find the object "a" created and point to it.

It's in the pool but it returns the `"foo"` object not the `new String("foo")` object so `==` is still false.

You can put an String into the pool with `.intern()` such as

```
String a = "food".substring(0, 3).intern();
String b = "foo";
assert a == b;
```

Answer (score 1):

`String a="foo";`

-> Check String pool, if String pool does not have one, create a new String Object in String pool

`String b="foo";`

-> Check String pool, if String pool contains it, make a reference to that String Object.

`String c=new String("foo");`

It directly create a new String Object outside the String pool but in Object pool(Memory).

At object point of view, the 2 String Object are identical, so if you use .equals to compare those 2, it returns true. But if you use == to compare, it compare the reference, which is not pointing toward the same object, so it return false.

for more details:
http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/strings/string-literal-pool/

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the way the pool works: when you do

```
String a = "foo";
```

the `String` object `"foo"` ends up in the pool not because you create it first, but because it is an object based on a *string literal* (a sequence of characters inside double-quotes). Java creates this object for you in the constant pool.

When you write

```
String a = new String("foo");
```

the string object `"foo"` from the pool is copied into a new `String` object, which is *not* placed in the pool.

Answer (score 0):

Even though common pool is typically part of the heap, the objects created through `new` never goes into pool, where as the literals used while creating goes to pool. When you compare literals what you said will be true. Not against a literal and an Object.

Answer (score -1):

String a does not go to string pool, String b does - so the references are different. That's why you get false.

Comment: There are three `String a` declarations here. Which one(s) are you talking about?